# What is the closure of the set $A=\{(1/n,0)\; |\; n \text{ is natural}\}$?

Tags: general-topology

> What is  the closure of the set $A=\{(1/n,0)\; |\; n \text{ is natural}\}$ ?

The closure is the intersection of all closed super sets but I am not understanding  what will be the closure of this set.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @MohammedAliRaza Is $A$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual topology?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I derive the closure of $\{1/n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944825/how-do-i-derive-the-closure-of-1-n-n-in-mathbbn)

Answer (score 1):

The closure of the set $A$ is $A\cup \{0\},$ which is the smallest closed set containing $A.$

Note that the only limit point of $A$ which is not in $A$ is $0,$ so the closure includes $0.$